# Python - format single quote in SQL statement PyODBC

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-2.7, pyodbc

I already tried a couple of drivers: pymsql, pyobdc and still have issue with format single quote in SQL. Examples of code below:

**CASE 1.**

```
import pyodbc

UPDATE_SQL3 = """
    UPDATE STATION
    SET
        STATION_NAME = ?,
        STATION_TITLE = ?,
        ACTIVE = ?
    WHERE
        STATION_ID = ?
"""

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=local;DATABASE=DB;UID=me;PWD=pass')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute(UPDATE_SQL3 %
                           (name,
                            title,
                            active,
                            id
                            ))
```

This code doesn't compile:

> "not all arguments converted during string formatting"

**CASE 2.**

```
UPDATE_SQL3 = """
    UPDATE STATION
    SET
        STATION_NAME = %s,
        STATION_TITLE = %s,
        ACTIVE = %s
    WHERE
        STATION_ID = %s
"""
```

I catch the error:

> ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near 'The'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

once `title = u'102.7 The Fan'`

**CASE 3.**

```
UPDATE_SQL3 = """
    UPDATE STATION
    SET
        STATION_NAME = '%s',
        STATION_TITLE = '%s',
        ACTIVE = %s
    WHERE
        STATION_ID = %s
"""
```

Error:

> ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near 's'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

where `name = u'Power Michiana\\'s Hits and Hip Hop'`

What is a correct approach to handling it?

Comment: for the case 3 do name = u'Power Michiana\'s Hits and Hip Hop'

Comment: How  can I do it correctly? I tried to replace the chars - `title = title.replace("\\", "")`, however I still see 

- `title = u'Power Michiana\\'s Hits and Hip Hop'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your "CASE 1" is essentially correct, but you are not passing the parameters to `conn.execute` properly. Instead of trying to use string formatting (via the `%` operator), simply pass the tuple as the second argument to the `.execute`, like this:

```python
import pyodbc

# test data
name = u"Power Michiana's Hits and Hip Hop"
title = u"(some title)"
active = False
id = 1

conn_str = "DSN=myDb_SQLEXPRESS"
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = conn.cursor()
UPDATE_SQL3 = """\
UPDATE STATION
SET
    STATION_NAME = ?,
    STATION_TITLE = ?,
    ACTIVE = ?
WHERE
    STATION_ID = ?
"""
cursor.execute(UPDATE_SQL3, (name, title, active, id))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
print("Done.")
```